# Check if input length and numbers only

Tags: c#, regex, string, input

I'm trying to code that it won't accept letters only numbers
and also it will check the range of the clipboard.gettext like this format

```
000_2019_1_20181234_111111111111
```

I successfully got some code when I copied

```
000_2019_1_20181234_111111111111
```

it will paste

```
2019_1_20181234_111111111111
```

but it accepts when I copy `2019_1_2` I want to reject it automatically, detect and remove when it has letters example
I copy

```
0aa_2019_1_20181234_1111AA111111
```

it will have a result like

`2019_1_20181234_1111` and also I copy
`2019_1_2A181234_1111` it will show invalid.
And `2019_1_2` shows invalid. the format I also want to accept is this kind `2019_1_20181234_1`

```
 public void txtboxBatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string copyBatchnumber = Clipboard.GetText();

      string batchNumber;


      batchNumber = copyBatchnumber.Replace("100_", "").Replace("000_", "")
                   .Replace("001_", "").Replace("002_", "")
                   .Replace("[a-z]", "").Replace("003_", "");

      Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9,_]+$");

      if (regex.IsMatch(batchNumber))
        {
          {
             MessageBox.Show("ok"); 
          }
       }
     else
       { 
         MessageBox.Show("invalid batchnumber"); 

       }
       txtboxBatch.Text = batchNumber;
     }
```

Comment: add Regex tag to your question

Comment: already added but can you give me sample or arrange my code thank you very much

Comment: Try `Regex(@"^[0-9]+(?:_[0-9]+){3,4}")` to validate, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzgkRq/1). To remove all non-valid chunks between `_`s, try this before validation: `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?:^|(_))[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*_", "$1")` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzgkRq/2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to get the pattern without having to replace undesired output.

**Regex :**

```
(.*?_)?(\d{4}_\d{1}_\d{8}(_\d+))(?!.*\w)
```

**Regex Explanation :**

```
(.*?_)? ---> every thing with non-greedy _ , it can exist or not
    (\d{4}_\d{1}_\d{8}(_\d+)) ---> Our desired pattern
    (?!.*\w) ---> negative look ahead in case we have 0aa_2019_1_20181234_1111AA111111
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B0-3%5D%2B_%29%3F%28%5Cd%2B_%5Cd%2B_%5Cd%2B_%5Cd%2B%29%28%3F!.*%5Cw%29&i=2019_1_20181234_11111%0D%0A2019_1_20181234_11A11%0D%0A2019_1_A20181234_1111%0D%0A2019_8_8)

**C# Code :**

```
            string pattern = @"(.*?_)?(\d{4}_\d{1}_\d{8}(_\d+))(?!.*\w)";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            string Data1 = @"0aa_2019_1_20181234_111111111111";
            string Data2 = @"2019_8_8";
            // First Sample
            Match Re = regex.Match(Data1);
            if(Re.Groups.Count < 2)
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(Re.Groups[2]);
            // Second Sample
            Re = regex.Match(Data2);
            if (Re.Groups.Count < 2)
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(Re.Groups[2]);
```

**Output**

```
2019_1_20181234_111111111111
Invalid Input!
```

**PS :** Basically the regex can interact even with the invalid data, in the end it will extract only the right pattern from the wrong one **"First Sample"** and it will reject the **"Second Simple"** which is not what we want.

Comment: hello thank you for this but how can trim or delete if the client input 0aa_2019_1_20181234_111111111111

it will replace to this 2019_1_20181234_111111111111
it will only accept Regex(@"^[(\d{4}_\d{1}_\d{8}_\d*)]+$") others will be deleted

Comment: ah so you wanna specify the length of the numerics symbols, the regex will be the same, did you test my code ? i wil do an update explaining some functionalities

Comment: hi thank you for you're code it did work but i want also if i input like this
0aa_2019_1_20181234_111111111111 it will automatically delete the 0aa_
and it will have the result 2019_1_20181234_111111111111 also if i input like this 000_2019_1_20181234_1aaa it will have the result 2019_1_20181234_1

thanks in advance

Comment: one week later ? i thought you did an effort to learn regex by now, good luck